# accessing the NSSet of my managed object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The app i'm working on consists of two classes which each belongs to a table view controller (you can say the app is similar to a master-detail app). in the first class and specifically in the prepareForSegue method, i passed an NSMangedObject so that the next view can add something to an attribute of the managed object.

i typed the following in the first class:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[SSCViewController class]]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [objects objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        SSCViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationViewController.managedObject = selectedObject;
    }
}
```

in the second class .h file it has the following property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *managedObject;
```

So, my data model consist of two entities having an inverse one-to-many relationship. i want to access the NSSet of the "managedObject" to see if it contains anything or to make sure an added entity is there. i tried [self.managedObject allObjects] and [self.managedObject hasObjects] but both didn't work (hasObjects is the name of the relationship between the managed object and the other entity). how can  i access the relationship of the managed object and return the NSSet?

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Comment: use the KVO getter `-valueForKey:` to fire a fault and get a proper value.

Comment: @H2CO3 mmm.. what do you mean by that?

Comment: @user1938695 I mean that this question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: @CodaFi in the managed object class it automatically generated methods which seems that helps to add and remove objects to the relationship NSSet property. do i use those to add to the property? actually i tried to use them but they seem private and i can't access them from another class. should i change their place or keep them there?

Comment: Whatever core data generates for you is always the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your core data attribute is named "toManyRelation" then use

```
NSSet *mySet = [self.managedObject valueForKey:@"toManyRelation"];
```

... and go from there.

I know from painful experience that these things are not too obvious when you start with this matter. But it turned out to be quite simple, once you know it.

Comment: okay how can i now add objects to the NSSet relation property? i tried accessing the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors method which seem to help add and remove objects to the NSSet but i can't. i guess they're private. can i change their place or is it best to keep them and use an alternative way?

Comment: It is a regluar NSSet. Make sure that you create proper NSManagedObjects of the same entity that the relation relates to and add them to the Set. I use setByAddingObject for that.

Comment: Well, if you auto-crate the model class for the core data entities, then it comes with a method with add... and remove... mehtods for each set. That may be more convenient for you then using the rather abstract KVC pattern.

Comment: Hi I am a little confused: Is *mySet just a random name or is it an actual name of a NSSet in the Core Data?

Comment: *mySet is a random name.